How is it best to implement is_active in FastAPI + JWT authentication?
I have model User which has a field is_active. If it's false, it means the user's account is blocked.
The question is how can I implement access restrictions in this case?
Should I just deny the user access to certain endpoints? And where is the best place to perform this check? Should it be in the get_current_user dependency if is_active = False?
async def get_current_user(
    db: SessionDep, token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
) -> User:
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )

    token_data = await verify_access_token(token, credentials_exception)

    result = await db.execute(select(User).where(User.id == token_data.id))
    user = result.scalar_one_or_none()

    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception

    return user


IMHO the best way is to use current_active_user from https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/latest/

Best way to achieve what you want is to check whether a user is active in the get_current_user dependency. This way you won't grand access to the API to an inactive user.
You can modify the dependency like this:
async def get_current_user(
    db: SessionDep, token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
) -> User:
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )

    token_data = await verify_access_token(token, credentials_exception)

    result = await db.execute(select(User).where(User.id == token_data.id))
    user = result.scalar_one_or_none()

    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception

    # New check is here
    if user.is_active is False:
       raise user_deactivated_exception # <- you will need to create a new exception to this case

    return user

Regarding whether users need access to certain endpoints, it all depends on the business logic. Do you have an API that might be accessible to inactive users? If this is the case, the simplest solution would be to create a dependency that solely checks if a user is active.
async def get_active_current_user(
    user = Depends(get_current_user)
) -> User:
    # New check is here
    if user.is_active is False:
       raise user_deactivated_exception # <- you will need to create a new exception to this case

    return user

With this approach you can use the get_current_user Dependency for endpoint which can be used by inactive users and the get_active_current_user for endpoints which can be only used by activated users.
